# Android is looking for a class in the wrong place after package rename

Tags: android

I cam across this issue today and thought it might help someone.
So it's a common practice to change the package name of a project to re-use some design and code elements, after one such change I've got this error while building the project.

```
Error: Activity class {com.oldpackagename/com.newname.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

The device was looking for the activity in the old package name for some reason, after cleaning my Manifest file I understood the issue was not in it.
Clean build, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart all failed.
When browsing the project folder I had no reference to

**Solution**

I was testing on a physical device, and a package name change was done between testing and during development, this made 2 icons of the same app. the solution was to uninstall it from the physical device. If you are using emulator it will be the same.

Comment: So this isn't a question?

Comment: Nope I thought it would help someone....